# Google TypeError: ScriptApp.newTrigger(...).forSpreadsheet(...).timeBased is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I get error message: "TypeError: ScriptApp.newTrigger(...).forSpreadsheet(...).timeBased is not a function.." (in both cases below)

```
function testTrigger1(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('processAccessRequests')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(30)
    .create(); 
}

function testTrigger2(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('processAccessRequests')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(30)
    .create(); 
}
```

Does this not work from a spreadsheet script? Or do I need to do something with authorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit :). It means that the function `timeBased()` **does not exist** in the [`SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder) class.

When you call [`forSpreadsheet(key)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#forspreadsheetkey) it returns a `SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder` object, hence the error when trying to call `timeBased()` on it.

If you are creating a trigger which is time based, irrelevant of the editor use the [`ClockTriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder). You get an instance of it by calling [`timeBased()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder#timebased) on a [`TriggerBuilder`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder) instance.

### Example:

```js
function timeTrigger(handler, mins){
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(handler)
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(mins)
    .create(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation !

Answer (score 2):

`forSpreadsheet()` is only used when you need a spreadsheet based trigger like edit from a spreadsheet or opening the spreadsheet.  For time based triggers, you don't need `forSpreadsheet`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!